# Look at topvoted questions for a particular tag

Tags: sx.el

In [sx-mode](https://github.com/vermiculus/sx.el) (a major mode for viewing StackExchange in Emacs), it is possible to look at the topvoted questions for a particular StackExchange site with `sx-tab-topvoted`. It is also possible to search for a particular tag with `sx-ask`. But as far as I can tell there is no way to combine the two without laboriously setting the user's favorite tags to be the query tag, and then sorting by "topvoted favorites".

For example, I would like to search the topvoted questions on Emacs StackExchange that are tagged with `[sx.el]`.